# How to resize text which is dynamically generated from API and input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text which is dynamically generated from API.

If I reload page then after 5 seconds text appears in `<div><h1>myText</h1></div>` and I can edit it in input.

I'm using this plugin http://leandropio.github.io/ng-fi-text/ - see how big is text?
I just want to resize font of texts which have length < 15 to 10px.

I got this code with jQuery code:

```js
myApp.directive('ng-fix-text', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // Pseudo jQuery code
            var text_len = $('.myDiv').find('h1').text().length;
            if (text_len < 15){
                    $('.myDiv').css('font-size', '10px')
        }
        }
    };
});
```

By the way, I don't want to intefere with code inside plugin.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Fixed the title + I just want to resize font of texts which have length < 15 to 10px.

Comment: Are you saying that the directive you linked to doesn't work the way you want and you therefore want to create another directive to adjust for it? Hard to understand the issue here. This question could use a much better problem explanation

Comment: I'm total noob in AngularJS. 
I just created this directive. 
Text is being dynamically generated from API. 
I just want to resize text inside div if length < 15

By the way, the plugin works perfectly

Comment: And your code is not working?

Comment: Um, no. Because it is written in jQuery.

Comment: You can use jQuery within angular app, so how do we know it doesn't work if you don't explain that?

Comment: I didn't even know that jQuery suppose to work inside Angular code.

Answer (score 1):

You can access each DOM element inside the declared directive exactly as with jQuery by using the `element` parameter declared in your `link` function. It's operating exactly as jQuery in fact it's jQuery abstraction.

First do not forget that in angular we refer to the directive by it's camel-cased normalized name.

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

So if you named your directive as `ng-fix-text` then you should refer to it as: `ng-fix-text`.

Here is the updated code:

```
myApp.directive('ngFixText', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var text_len = element.find('h1').text().length;
            if (text_len < 15) {
                    element.find('h1').css('font-size', '10px')
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this works only for 'static' text inside html. Not dynamically generated.

Comment: I don't really understand your point. You can modify the dynamically generated text as you wish as much as you have access to it

Comment: I found the problem. The plugin I mentioned in my post `ng-fi-text `generate another div `<div ng-fix-text ng-fi-text ><div>Text</div></div>`. 
Anyway Angular still can't change the font size

Comment: Here is the problem with full code

http://plnkr.co/edit/8sDBaJrrQBZS1AGMMyJS?p=preview